# jQuery Dropdown Mouseover two different elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I want to create a mouseover dropdown navigation (which works with tap on mobile/ipad as well) and have the problem, that the menu itself is in a complete different div. So not a child of that element.

```
 jQuery('.top-menu').on("mouseover",function(){ 
            jQuery(".top-menu-dropdown").stop().slideToggle(200,'easeOutCubic');  
   });
```

The div which is triggering that the menu slides down is .top-menu once hovered but I have the problem that I have to add the top-menu-dropdown class to it so it's closing as soon as the user exits the menu. And how can I add a short delay that the menu is not closing as soon as the cursor leaves it? (Stopping timer when you enter it again ofc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write it more like this using the jquery hover function which has both the mouse over and mouse out built in as shown below.

```
jQuery('.top-menu').hover(
  // Mouseover
  function(){ jQuery(".top-menu-dropdown").stop().slideDown(200,'easeOutCubic'); },
  // Mouseout
  function(){ jQuery(".top-menu-dropdown").stop().slideUp(200,'easeOutCubic'); }
);
```

Replcace slideup and slidedown with whatever direction you would like :)

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Sure it works but as soon as I leave the top-menu div the menu (which has the top-menu-dropdown class) is closing.

When you are in the top-menu-dropdown area the menu should stay open as well :)

Comment: Ya that has more to do with your HTML structure, if say your $('.top-menu') element was wrapping around the $('.top-menu-dropdown') you would effectively still be hovering over $('.top-menu') while $('top-menu-dropdown') remained open.  But because you have them as two unrelated items you will not be able to use mouseover/mouseout to effectively trigger the menu opening/closeing.

Comment: And there is no workaround to get it working with my current menu structure?

Comment: Not very elegantly no.  You could try to use a $('.top-menu').mouseover(open it) with a $('.top-menu-dropdown').mouseout(closeit) but it would be choppy at best.